# To check mersenne numbers in JAVA using bitwise operator

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I want help in finding the mersenne numbers using bitwise/bitshift operators.
For every run of the program, the program examines a given number range which is defined by constants.

> Example : the range 3430..3440.

I checked the internet and got this property of mersenne numbers: A Mersenne number consist of only 1 in the binary representation. The first numbers are 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127.

How can I check mersenne numbers using bitshift operators of java and logical opertors?

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you need ? Total number of `Mersenne number` in between the range or the actual `Mersenne numbers`?

Comment: Actual Mersenne numbers within the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mersenne numbers can be listed easily by taking the previous Mersenne number and appending/prepending/put-it-wherever a 1:

```
long nextMersenne(long previous) {
    return (previous << 1) | 1;
}
```

You can find the lowest Mersenne number not-less-than a given number by "sweeping" the leftmost set bet to the right, setting everything in its path, eg

```
1001101
1101101
1111101
1111111
```

Which you can compute like this:

```
long lowestMersenneNotLessThan(long lowerBound) {
    long x = lowerBound;
    x |= x >> 1;
    x |= x >> 2;
    x |= x >> 4;
    x |= x >> 8;
    x |= x >> 16;
    x |= x >> 32;
    return x;
}
```

So you can start there, then keep generating the next higher Mersenne number with the first function, until it grows larger than the upper bound (or becomes -1, which happens after enumerating the highest Mersenne number that fits in a `long`, if you want to go higher you can do the same thing with more annoying syntax with a `BigInteger`).

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`BigInteger` has a nice function `bitCount` which will count how many bits are set in the number. Notice that any mersenne number plus 1 will have just one bit set.

```
public boolean isMersenne(int n) {
    // If it is mersenne (i.e. 2^n -1) then n + 1 will have just ONE set bit.
    return (BigInteger.valueOf(n+1).bitCount() == 1);

}

public void test() {
    int count = 0;
    for ( int i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
        if ( isMersenne(i)) {
            System.out.println(i + " is mersenne!");
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("There are "+count);
}
```

Comment: What about `Time-Complexity` of the suggested approach?

Comment: And also in question , It is mentioned that `How can I check mersenne numbers using bitshift operators of java and logical opertors?`